# how to execute javascript code inside php?

Tags: javascript, php

php file

```
<button id='submit' name='submit' ><h1>Schedule</h1></button>
<?php
      include 'dbres.php';
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $sql = "UPDATE reserved SET reserved = false WHERE reserved = true;";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        echo'document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
        this.textContent = "reserved";
        }';
      }
    ?>
```

I want the javascript code inside the php code to changes the text from submit to reserved. I have tested the javascript code and it works by itself, but doesn't seem to work in php.

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client, PHP on the server. The code runs in different places at different times. You simply can't do this.

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript for this? What not generate HTML based on the output of PHP?

Comment: You should also make your PHP code only viewable/executable for the server. Move all your PHP into separate files and set proper permissions for them.

Comment: I could only find ways of changing html text using javascript. If I use PHP to check if the button has been clicked on I'm not sure I could change the text using html.@Dharman

Comment: @hewiefreeman do you want me to leave the javascript code in this file and have it reference a different php file?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot echo JS inside PHP, they are two separate languages. If you want to have the client run the JS, you can use the script tag:

```
echo '<script>
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
        this.textContent = "reserved";
    }
</script>';
```

Comment: Yeah I copied and pasted your code but it doesn't seem to be working since the text hasn't changed.

Comment: check devtools, are there any errors showing in console or was the `script` element added at all?

Comment: So this is the error I received in the console but it references a css file. ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: make sure you put the `echo '<script>....` in the correct place. Also, are you referring to the text not changing before or after you press the submit button?

Comment: This is the exact code: ```<button id='submit' name='submit' ><h1>Schedule</h1></button>
    <?php
      include 'dbres.php';
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $sql = "UPDATE reserved SET reserved = false WHERE reserved = true;";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        echo '<script>
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
            this.textContent = "reserved";
        }
        </script>';
        }
    ?>```I am referring to after the button has been pressed.

Comment: This should function as intended, I see nothing wrong with it...

Comment: I think Tangentially Perpendicular is right javascript and PHP are not combinedable.